# How to add spaces in function brackets in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some string like this i need to add space before and after the `' ('` and `') '` in php

```
$var =  '(These 4 containers include all example container)';
```

So what i tried is

```
   $frontbraket = str_replace('(', ' (',$var);
   echo str_replace(')', ') ',$frontbraket);
```

How can i make this simple by using `preg_replace` ?

Comment: [Whats wrong with this. Its working fine](https://eval.in/412886)

Answer (score 1):

You can also make an array within `str_replace` like as

```
echo str_replace(['(',')'], [' (',') '],$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(.*?)$/', ' $1 ', $var);
```

**Note: This will add spaces on both sides for any string. `(`, `)` are not checked.**

Comment: I agree it uses preg_replace as asked :) But if it's supposed to add spaces to any string then $str = ' ' . $str . ' '; will do :)

Comment: Agree. :D We don't know what OP wants to do with this. Else would have suggested accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/^\((.+)\)$/', ' ($1) ', $var);
```